# how to pass value from java to ireport mysql statement

Tags: java, mysql, ireport

I have a form where I have to set two dates. after that I want to generate a report from ireport. How can I pass that two dates to the ireport mysql statements? Am null in ireport.

Answer (score 0):

define your variables as parameter in date type. and put them parameter map<> before rendering report.

then you can use these parameters any where of ireport like sql, variable or page header.